If sending multiple HTTP GET requests using for loop, why is aiohttp still faster than requests?
I am following the code in this page: https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python-with-aiohttp.
Here is the first approach using aiohttp:
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

start_time = time.time()


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for num in range(1, 10):
            pokemon_url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{num}'
            async with session.get(pokemon_url) as response:
                pokemon_json = await response.json()
                print(pokemon_json['name'], num)


asyncio.run(main())

print(f'{time.time() - start_time} seconds')


If I understand it correctly, the for loop executes session.get synchronously thus the GET request are sent out sequentially. In each iteration of the for loop, the await keyword causes the main coroutine to pause, and event loop has no other coroutine to execute and all it does is wait for response.json() to return the result. Asynchronous Programming is not giving any extra performance improvement here.
Approach 2 is the regular approach using requests. It's also executed synchronously:
import requests
import time

start_time = time.time()

for num in range(1, 10):
    url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{num}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    pokemon = response.json()
    print(pokemon['name'])

print(f'{time.time() - start_time} seconds')


The approach 1 took 3.581976890563965 seconds. Approach 2 took 8.428680419921875 seconds. Since they both executed GET requests sequentially, what's the reason for approach 1
using aiohttp still being faster than approach 2 using requests?

To compare performance directly, I think you'd need to use a Session in your requests example as well: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session
Otherwise, aiohttp is able to use a keep-alive connection, while requests is needing to create a whole new session on each request (in the aiohttp docs we always use the session so people write production-ready code from the start, while many other libraries don't even mention this until an advanced section or similar).

@SamBull Thanks! You are right. After using a requests.Session with a context manager in approach 2, the two approaches have similar time spent.

requests is a synchronous library which means it blocks until each request is completed before moving on to the next one. This cause the delay,
aiohttp is an asynchronous library that uses asyncio to handle requests concurrently without blocking the execution of the code. This allows aiohttp to process multiple requests in parallel, resulting in faster overall performance compared to the sequential approach of requests

In my approach 1 using aiohttp, I used a for loop to send the requests (just for testing purpose). In this case, the GET requests are not processed asynchronously in my opinion.
